# Java Swap Event Threads

Tags: java

I have a code: this is matrix with red, blue values that i need for a project. I need to click on some button then on neighbor and their values should be swapped(red has key 1,blue key 2),and so on. I think I should create it by threads somehow(sorry for inaccuracy), but as i understand, one button should be clicked(new Thread started), second button(Thread stopped,swap made) and values changed.

I understand, that my question can be some "tutorial" or basic but this is complicated for me and I cant find an answer for a long time.Thank you for any advice or an example.

```
public class  ButtonsMatrix extends JButton {

private int[][] fModel;
private  int fX;
private  int fY;

public ButtonsMatrix( int x,  int y,  int[][] model) {
    fX= x;
    fY= y;
    fModel= model;


    /*addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Update();
        }


    });*/
     updateNameFromModel();
}

private void updateNameFromModel() {
    fModel[fX][fY] = (int)(Math.random()*2);
    setText(String.valueOf(fModel[fX][fY]));
    if(fModel[fX][fY] == 1){
        setText("Red");
    } else {
        setText("Blue");
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dim=7;
        int matrix[][] = new int[7][7];

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Window containing a matrix");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JPanel extra = new JPanel(new CardLayout(290,300));
       TextField tf = new TextField();
       tf.setBounds(800,20,20,20);
       f.add(tf);


        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(dim, dim));
        for( int r = 0; r < dim; r++){
            for( int c = 0; c < dim; c++){
                ButtonsMatrix button= new ButtonsMatrix(r, c, matrix);



                p.add(button);
            }
        }

        extra.add(p);


        f.setLocation(350, 100);
        f.add(extra);

        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

}

Comment: I would start out without threading, as threading makes your program much more complex, and not necessarily faster. If you run into the problem that you are performing too much work on the UI thread - then the time has come to start multithreading your program.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but i will need a thread because, according to a project,  the swap action will be recorded in label.

Comment: In fact you've already asked this question, one that has been answered, and you've already been asked *why* you think that you need threads because I can tell you that both @M.leRutte and myself see no need for threading at all based on what you've so far posted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for each of the buttons to know anything about any other button.
Just create the button matrix and add an ActionListener to each button. On the first click, just save that button reference. On next click, interchange info of the two buttons and set the saved ID to null. Outline:

```
public class MyClass {
   private JButton clicked = null;

   public void main( String[] args ) {
      ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
            if ( clicked == null ) {
               clicked = b;
            } else {
               if ( b != clicked) {
                  // swap info between b and clicked
               }
               clicked = null;
            }
         }
      };
      // create matrix here, adding the above listener to each button.
      ...

   }
}
```